# Struts plugin for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, struts

Are there any Struts plugins available for Eclipse?

Comment: [StrutsClipse](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/strutsclipse)

Answer (score 0):

There is also [MyEclipse](http://www.myeclipseide.com/) which has integrated support for Struts.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do this is to download the latest version of MyEclipse. Within MyEclipse you can add Struts capabilities to your web projects and MyEclipse will add the necessary jars etc for you, you don't have to do a thing.

Answer (score -1):

It is a little known fact, but [Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/eclipse/overview/index.html) is the best tool out there for Struts and it is now free for regular use. You can read more about this tool in [my post](http://blog.zvikico.com/2008/08/the-best-jspstrutsjsf-development-tool-is-now-free.html). The features are still there, Oracle just don't advertise it very well on their site.